# Saturn's Pan and Prometheus orbital resonance

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, moons, saturn, orbital-resonance

Is it possible for a small object (such as a manned capsule) to realize a maneuver using the orbital resonance influence of Saturn's moons Pan and Prometheus?

Comment: Is any maneuvering possible, or are you just wondering about the $n$-body problem with natural orbital effects?

Comment: A manned capsule would not exert much gravitational force on a second body - so mutual resonance effects would probably be quite difficult to measure. (But, it would be good if you added a little more detail to your question to see if this is exactly what you mean.)

Comment: Sending a manned capsule to Saturn would be a very long journey without return to earth. It is not even possible to transport the necessary life support system to saturn using available rockets. Only a unmanned mission would be possible.

Comment: @Uwe `Only a unmanned mission would be possible.` This implies that it will *never* be possible. It probably will be, someday.

Comment: Orbital resonance is how the gravity of two objects that have certain relationships between their orbital periods causes their orbits to change over time. This doesn't create effects at other points in space, like Lagrange points do. [Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(moon)) and [Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(moon)) are both very small moons and there is no resonance between them. The orbit of a vessel in a very high orbit can be affected by the gravity of other bodies   enough to require station-keeping to stay in position, but these bodies are too small for that

Comment: The point is not about how to get there, or even come back. But saturn's rings are shaped by his moons, that means gravitational infulence of the moons. And the infulence on the capsule? Could a stranded capsule use this influence to change his orbit?

PD: @NathanTuggy edited my question and "blew away fluff" about the original meaning. Thank you, very, very much.

Comment: @ShinsVerShynt: If you feel that the point of the original question is not well represented by my edit, you can roll it back, but as far as I can tell, the question preserves all the essential points and none of the non-essential ones. The fact that you're writing a story is barely relevant if at all; the fact that the capsule is stranded scarcely more so.